# check server response with curl -D

Tags: linux, curl

As far as i can see from the man curl page, the -D option should provide me with the server response to the request i'm sending.
When i try to read the file i need, stored on the server i'm connecting to, i can read it properly:

```
curl -uUSERNAME:PASS SERVER-NAME/path-to-file > my_output
```

This is successful, so i can acces properly with the credentials i use.
Now i would like to create a pre-reading validation step, that first reads the response to my access attempt, if a 200 OK is received, go ahead with requesting the file...
So i use

```
curl -D -uUSERNAME:PASS SERVER-NAME > my_output
```

Now i get a 401 response, i dont get it:

```
<title>401 Authorization Required</title>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
intvar=$(curl -s -w %{http_code} http://SERVER-NAME/path-to-file -o /dev/null)
case $intvar in
    4*|5*)
        echo >&2 "Fatal: HTTP $intvar code spotted."
        exit 1
    ;;
    2*|3*)
        echo "HTTP $intvar code spotted."
        # 2nd curl command
    ;;
esac
```

See :

```
man curl | less +/^' *-w'
```

Comment: Hi sputnick, thx for the solution, but what it makes this to work in comparison to -D? your solution simply makes it silent, and fetches a variable passed to the -w option, i dont understand why -D opton would not work why would